# Android Studio el código me da error pero cuando lo pongo antes del If me funciona

Tags: java, android-studio

¿Por qué cuando pongo `num2 = calificacion.getText().toString()` y `num3 =Double.parseDouble(num2)` donde se muestra en el código me da error; pero cuando lo pongo antes del `If` me funciona el programa sin problemas? Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
package com.alumno.calificacion;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText alumno;
private EditText calificacion;
private Button comprobar;
private Button limpiar;
private TextView salida;
private String nota;
private Double num3;
private String num2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alumno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InAlumno);
    calificacion= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InCalificacion);
    comprobar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnComprobar);
    limpiar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLimpiar);
    salida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Error);
    num2 = calificacion.getText().toString();
    num3 =Double.parseDouble(num2);

    comprobar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //aqui es donde me refiero 
            if(num3 >=0 && num3 <=10.5)
                nota = "Malo";
            else if(num3 >10 && num3 <=14)
                nota="Regular";
            else if(num3 >15 && num3 <=18)
                nota="Bueno";
            else if (num3 >19 && num3 <=20)
                nota="Excelente";

            salida.setText("El alumno "+nota);
        }
    });

    limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alumno.setText("");
            calificacion.setText("");
            salida.setText("");
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Y por cierto, ya no hace falta que hagas un cast de tipo al hacer el metodo findViewById -> Desde la API 26 es redundante y te devuelve el tipo directamente el tipo sin necesidad de castearlo. Y para la siguiente vez: resume tu pregunta en el título que 'Tengo una duda de Android Studio' puede ser muy general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que cuando lees el valor del `EditText` `calificacion` no hay nada y devuelve nulo, cosa que provoca error al hacer un `Double.parseDouble`. Como bien dices, tendrás que poner ese código dentro `onClick(View v)`

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

En el `onCreate()` fijate que tu `EditText` calificación no contiene nada (es nulo). Y al obtener un `getText()` te da un null pointer exception.

Igualmente, en añadido a lo que ha comentado Javi Mollá, yo me aseguraría que tu `EditText` calificacion tenga un valor o si no, de nuevo, te lo devolverá como null.